# Pyspark convert complex Dataformat

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

reading a parquet file with spark

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("path_to_file")
df.show(2)
```

my df contains

```py
**Output**

+------+-----------------+
| col1 |       col2      |
+------+-----------------+
| "A1" |  {"x":1,"y":2}  |
+------+-----------------+
| "A2" |  {"z":3}        |
+------+-----------------+
```

I want to convert the dataframe to like

```py
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 |  x   |  y   |  z   |
+------+------+------+------+
| "A1" |  1   |  2   | Null |
+------+------+------+------+
| "A2" | Null | Null |  3   |
+------+------+------+------+
```

schema of initial dataframe shows

```py
DataFrame[col1: string, col2: string]
```

I am using pyspark 2.3.2 on windows 7 machine

Comment: you only have x,y and z or you can have a lot of different value ? Do you have an exhaustive list of values ?

Comment: the contents of `col2` are JSON encoded as string data, Spark doesn't know anything about it, you will need to parse the contents of that column

Comment: @Steven there is no fixed length of data that i can get in col2, so if some new key(eg 'w') comes in i want to add it as a new column

Comment: What is your version of spark ?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not exactly what you asked for but maybe you didnt think it that way. Therefore, please, add comments if it does not suit you.

```
> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
> from pyspark.sql.types import *

> df.show()
+----+-------------+
|col1|         col2|
+----+-------------+
|  A1|{"x":1,"y":2}|
|  A2|      {"z":3}|
+----+-------------+

> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)

> df = df.withColumn(
..  "col2",
..  F.from_json("col2", MapType(StringType(),IntegerType()))
..)

> df.show()
+----+----------------+
|col1|            col2|
+----+----------------+
|  A1|[x -> 1, y -> 2]|
|  A2|        [z -> 3]|
+----+----------------+

> df.select(
..    "col1",
..    "col2.x",
..    "col2.y",
..    "col2.z",
..).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|   x|   y|   z|
+----+----+----+----+
|  A1|   1|   2|null|
|  A2|null|null|   3|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: The solution is workable for me but getting this error **Py4JJavaError** : `An error occurred while calling o2628.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'jsontostructs(`col2`)' due to data type mismatch: Input schema map<string,int> must be a struct or an array of structs.;;`

Comment: @TusharKolhe The sample data you provided are probably too simple. Your real case is I think far more complicated and my simple solution is not enough ! Please provide a real case.

Comment: I think the error states we cannot provide schema of type map (we set it as `Maptype(StringType(),IntergerType()))` , rather it requires `StructType()`

Comment: @TusharKolhe If you try your own example with my solution, is it working ? Does the error occur or does it occur only on your real dataset ? if you have an error on the sample, it is a version problem. If you have the error on your dataset only, i need more informations on your data.

Comment: Error occurs on the sample data too. I am using pyspark 2.3.2 on windows 7 machine

Comment: @TusharKolhe tried it with both spark 2.3.1 and 2.4.0 .... both are working. Sorry, but I do not know where the error comes from.